# filter for elements inside an array

Tags: mongodb

```
"dammfield" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60705d602ba9490026482370"),
            "f1" : ISODate("2021-04-09T10:57:52.152-03:00"),
            "f2" : ISODate("2021-04-09T10:57:52.152-03:00"),
            "f3" : ISODate("2022-04-09T10:57:52.152-03:00"),
            "f4" : ObjectId("5efa2c4977d67e002763c5ee"),
            "f5" : true,
            "f6" : "VALID",
            "f7" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ef39d0c80478000278879e5"),
                "ff1" : "123123123",
                "ff2" : "9812378921738127839"
            }
        }
    ],
```

I would like to know how can i filter elements inside an array that have another element.

i'm trying everything:

```
db.mycollection.find({ dammfield: { $elemMatch: { "f7.ff1": "123123123" }}})


db.mycollection.find({
        dammfield: {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: []
        }
    }, {
        dammfield: 1
    })
    .sort({
        _id: -1
    })
    .limit(1000)
```

How can I filter all documents that  have dammfield.f7.ff1 = something?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array using the `$elemMatch` *projection* operator (this is different from the `$elemMatch` query operator).

```
db.collection.find( { }, { dammfield: { $elemMatch: { "f7.ff1": "123123123" } } } )
```

You can also use the aggregate operator `$filter` with the same result.